# Facing issue for decryption of environment variables using AWS KMS in Micronaut

Tags: spring-boot, java-11, micronaut

I have a Spring Boot application which I am migrating to Micronaut. This application reads the environment variables on AWS Lambda and the variables are encrypted using KMS. I used the SpringBootServletInitializer to get the variables from KMS and decrypt it before the data source formation. The same is not working in Micronaut. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can override the environment property source, however that won't solve the issue with placeholders. Please file an issue on github asking for an enhancement to allow this functionality

Comment: @JamesKleeh Yes, I have asked the same question on GitHub as well.